# Is Sencha Touch's syntax similar to ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am going to learn Sencha Touch so it's interesting for me if i should learn ExtJS basics first to better understanding of Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very similar, yes.
Biggest difference to me has been the way the 2 frameworks handle the proposed architecture (MVC). ExtJS 4 do not (yet) have Ext.Dispatch, which means your controller logic becomes more oriented around listening to events. Touch MVC on the other hand can use Ext.Dispatch for program flow, which I like better. I guess it is personal preference, though.

Regarding your second question about if you should learn ExtJS first, I'd say it is entirely up to what you want to do. Learning one is pretty much learning the other. If mobile is what you are interested in, which it sounds like, then go for Touch directly. There are some brilliant Touch tutorials, fx:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:A_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap

Comment: There is a lot more content about Ext JS available (including books) if language/framework/syntax is your biggest challenge, but it just depends on your personal needs.  Also, I'll point out that the divergence between Ext and Touch architecturally -should be- temporary. They share the same platform code and the differences in architecture should mostly go away in the next major versions of each.

Answer (score 3):

Sencha Touch is built on Ext JS.  So, yes.

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar, but I don't see any need to learn ExtJS first.  Sencha Touch has some niceties that ExtJS doesn't have.  There's definitely no basics in ExtJS that you couldn't learn just as easily learning Sencha Touch. In some cases it might be distracting to sort out the differences between the two while learning, so I would stick with one until you feel solid with it.

Answer (score 1):

They are similar - but just different enough to be slightly painful to develop a combined desktop / mobile app at the same time.

Sencha Touch is certainly being changed at a break neck speed and adheres more to the MVC model of design. Having said that, however, you ultimately should decide based on how you wish to use your app - via desktop or mobile device.

Certainly I have more fun developing the mobile apps - but of course, desktop apps are still more robust and accessible to far more potential users / clients.

As a last note - I would suggest trying to build a simple app in both ExtJs and Sencha Touch using MVC structure - once you get that down the rest comes pretty easily.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

I would skip Ext JS for now unless you plan to learn it for its own sake.  I have learned Sencha Touch on its own and used it professionally without learning Ext JS per se.  They are indeed very similar, but Sencha Touch is neither a superset nor a subset of Ext JS.  Now especially with Sencha Touch 2, as Shildrak noted, some features of Sencha Touch are indeed more advanced.  I imagine the two may share more code (or at least more explicitly) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Sencha Touch then i highly recommend to study Javascript and HTML CSS because everything in sencha is based on Javascript and modifies HTML & CSS...

After thoroughly understanding Javascript theory concepts such as Objects, Arrays, Scopes, Delegation, Event Handling and Closures Sencha would be a piece of cake to you. Studying ExtJS is optional although you dont need to know it to learn sencha.